# Calculate difference between two datetime in MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am in the process of learning ASP.NET and MVC with Entity Framework, which is why this question may seem trivial to some of you.

My objective is relatively simple:
I have a model (Hour.cs) like this:

```
public class Hour
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int UsrID { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:HH:mm}")]
    public DateTime StartDateTime { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:HH:mm}")]
    public DateTime EndDatetime { get; set; }
    public int? ProjectID { get; set; }
    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
    public virtual Usr Usr { get; set; }
}
```

I currently have a view that shows information in a table/list:
`StartDateTime`,`EndDateTime`, `UsrID`, `ProjectID`

I want to add a column for TotalHrs represented by the difference between `StartDateTime` and `EndDateTime`.

To get the difference I have read numerous articles telling me to use timespan somewhere in the lines of:

```
Timspan diff = StartDateTime - EndDateTime;
```

What I do not understand is where to insert this code. I am assuming it is in the controller, but I do no understand how. 
My Index method looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var hours = db.Hours
            .Include(c => c.Usr)
            .Include(p => p.Project);

                   return View(hours.ToList());
    }
```

Any pointers appreciated!

Comment: What do you intend to do with the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would oppose to store such calculation on the database, when you can easily do it on client side as you have all the necessary information.

Add a new property and specify just a get accesor:

```
public class Hour
{
   // ...
   [NotMapped]
   public TimeSpan TotalHrs
   {
       get
       {
           return this.StartDateTime - this.EndDatetime;
       }
   }
   // ...
}
```

Then you can just access it like any other property in your view, controller or any class that consumes it.

```
TimeSpan val = hour.TotalHrs;
```

Comment: Just a note that `TotalHrs` can not be used in an EF/Linq-2-Sql query. The LINQ statement must be Linq-2-Objects (It needs to operate on an Enumerable as opposed to a Queryable).